# Is the order of the value inside the CLASSPATH matter?

Tags: java, classpath

I have 2 java program located seperately
One in c:\test and the other in c:\test\new

I can compile both of it without any error \javac

But when i try to execute the file \java
it shows the error like this

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ButtonFrame.makeButton(ButtonTest3.java:42)
    at ButtonFrame.<init>(ButtonTest3.java:29)
    at ButtonTest$1.run(ButtonTest.java:17)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i put this in my classpath

> CLASSPATH value-  C:\test;C:\test\new

but if i change the order of the value in CLASSPATH to this

> CLASSPATH value-  C:\test\new;C:\test

the error is simply gone

Why?? this could happening
Only the order matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a class with the same name in the both folders. In `C:\test` there's a version of the `ButtonTest3` class which contains a programming bug causing this `NullPointerException`. In `C:\test\new` there's a different version of the `ButtonTest3` class which doesn't contain this bug, or probably there's a `ButtonTest` class which does entirely different things than the one in `C:\test`.

Cleanup your classpath. It's not good to have duplicate different versioned classes with the same signature in the classpath. If your intent is that `new` is supposed to be a package identifier, then you need to leave it away from the classpath. However, such a package name would have resulted in a compilation error, so that can't be it.

---

As to the bug, a `NullPointerException` is relatively trivial to naildown and fix. First look at the first line of the stacktrace:

```
at ButtonFrame.makeButton(ButtonTest3.java:42)
```

It's telling that it has occurred in line 42 of `ButtonTest3` class, inside the `makeButton()` method. Now go to line 42 of `ButtonTest3.java`, it'll look something like:

```
someObject.doSomething();
```

Look there where a dot operator `.` is been used to invoke a method or access a field of some object. The `NullPointerException` means that `someObject` is `null` at the particular moment. There is no instance!

It's an easy fix: just ensure that it is *not* `null` at the moment you're invoking/accessing it:

```
someObject = new SomeObject();
// ...
someObject.doSomething();
```

Comment: it takes a while for me to think, but at last i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't believe you can have two classes defined in a single source file. You can have them defined as a subclass.

According to the [Java spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.htmlformat.):

> Each `class` file contains the
>   definition of a single class or
>   interface. Although a class or
>   interface need not have an external
>   representation literally contained in
>   a file (for instance, because the
>   class is generated by a class loader),
>   we will colloquially refer to any
>   valid representation of a class or
>   interface as being in the `class` file
>   format.format.

You could place `ButtonFrame` inside `ButtonTest2`.

```
public class ButtonTest2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       ...
       ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
    }

    class ButtonFrame extends JFrame {
       ....
   }
}
```

Or, put them in different java files.

Comment: oh right, i totally forgot that. 


btw i have decided to edit the question to be more specific to what i really curious about

Comment: Hmm, in the future, you should be asking a new question about that. Don't reuse old questions for completely different problems. Consider rollbacking your edit and asking a new question. Then I'll move my answer there as well.

Comment: i tried to put the ButtonFrame inside the ButtonTest2
but there's an error, i need to declare the 'static' somewhere. i couldn't find it

Comment: Woah, the question completely changed from when I answered it :)

Comment: I wonder if I should delete my answer now, because it is irrelevant to the question now since it got changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes at top level in program, thats wrong. But keeping that aside, your program is not getting compiled at first place.
To successfully compile the program use the following NppExec script:

```
cmd /c cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
cmd /k cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" "$(NAME_PART)" && exit
```

Make sure that you have your JDK folder set to `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.
and try again.

Comment: i was using that 3 lines script i found in the internet but feeling that its not working correctly,
now with ur script its really work!